# Young avocado plant moves to soil for a week and leaves are drying and pointing down

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, avocado

[image]

Hi guys, am looking for advice for my young avocado plant which has stop growing and leaves curling and pointing downward as in the picture. Moves it from water to soil a week ago and it doesn't get better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably quite normal for a late transplant and will rapidly recover. Since it was germinated on water it has been living entirely from resources inside the seed; these have been depleted and the leaves are showing some signs of stress with veins prominent against lighter leaf surface. It now has to learn to pull nutrients from the soil through the roots. Provided the root was not damaged too much in the move to soil all should be well if the new soil is kept evenly moist but not wet. If the root was broken during the move then re-establishment can take longer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The roots are in good condition. Probably water too much that the soil become wet and the roots has difficulty growing.

Comment: Mine did that as well, it hasn't recovered for about 2 months now. It is still 'healthy' but sad-looking though. Growing has stopped but I think it is because of lack of sun (Winter here now)